# Add comments to mysql queries (php -> mysql-db)

Tags: php, mysql, logging, phpmyadmin

I got a website with a lot functions and calculations and it grows every day. Calculation errors are getting harder to solve as my loggs are really big.

The website is used by employees, so there is a lot of traffic between the website and the mysql database. Is it possible in any way to append comments to the queries so they show up in the log-files?

The standart ones (I guess #..#) get lost after the query is parsed from the mysql-server.
Im just trying to get a better overview about my log-files.

For example it could be something like this:

```
$query  = "UPDATE something SET column = 'input' WHERE ... #ticket-calc#";
$result = mysql_query($query, $db) or die(mysql_error());
```

I would like to show up 'ticket-calc' for this query in the log-files.
Everything I tried hasnt worked. It looks like the server is saving just the raw-command without anything appended.

I also thought about just comparing a string (the comment) with 'true' what shouldnt change the general query.

> [query] ... AND 'ticket-calc'= true

I hope there is a more clean way to get it.

**Solved this by using /* comment */. Thanks!**

Comment: have you tried with `$query  = "UPDATE something SET column = 'input' WHERE ... /*ticket-calc*/";`?

Comment: You could write an udf.

Comment: or tried with `--` ?

Comment: Give me a sec. Ill try this out.

Comment: both mine and @davidkonrad's should work

Comment: A much more elegant option (IMHO) would be logging your queries yourself in a separate log file. Since you already are planning to manually edit your code where queries are issued, I would rather invoke a custom log manager. As a beneficial side-effect, you can decide precisely which queries get logged.

Comment: David's solution brings up an sql-error (unknown column <comment>). Yours (Alex's) is working. Post as an answer so I can close this.

Comment: @RandomSeed: That would result in logging quite everything. I dont want to save just specific queries as closely all queries are important. I just want to be able jumping through the log-files with text-search without searching for hole sql-queries rather than searching for simple comments I added.

Comment: @davidkonrad: --'comment' works.

Comment: You could log the actual query along with your custom message. This also allows you to log additional info, such as callstack and the like. This is just my opinion, though.

Comment: @RandomSeed: Ah yes I understand. But that would be a bigger thing to do. Im really looking for a simple way. I already got enough problems with the calculations. I will blow up myself if there will be even more problems just because of saving comments to queries. ^^ But thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one of the ppl who helped me out in the comments want to post their solutions as an answer, Ill do so to get this topic closed.

Im using /* .. */ to mark my queries.

*Thanks for the help @AlexGreg, @davidkonrad and @davidkonrad.*

Answer (score 0):

I have same approach to log (in MySQL) where are my queryes in database. I use "--" to solve the problem.

```php
$pdo->exec("-- GETTING USERS");
$stmt->execute();
```

By the way, is better make all logs in your application, inclusive, log over querys. Aka

```
file_put_contents('TRY TO EXECUTE QUERY: ' . $stmt->queryString);
$stmt->execute();
```